# How to load MacOS from an APFS partition using GRUB2?

Tags: grub, efi, apfs

This is a Apple machine, not a Hackintosh. Before Apple switched to APFS, you could put this inside a menu entry in GRUB:

```
set root=(your OS X partition)
chainloader /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
```

But that doesn't work with APFS, as GRUB can't read it, despite the EFI having drivers for AFPS.

Is there a way to have an option in the GRUB menu to boot MacOS? Some possibilities for how this might work:

- Somehow get GRUB to utilize the EFI's built-in APFS driver to load the MacOS bootloader
- Put the MacOS bootloader in a place where GRUB can read it
- Use GRUB to launch a 3rd-party EFI program that can load MacOS

*Sometimes* typing `exit` in the GRUB console will load MacOS, but it's not consistent—it will sometimes power off the machine, load GRUB again, or load another OS that is installed.

Comment: I ended up using a rEFInd installation configured to boot straight into MacOS without a delay. REFInd can be loaded straight from GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested these, so I'm not 100% sure they work.

> Somehow get GRUB to utilize the EFI's built-in APFS driver to load the MacOS bootloader

You can try copying the apfs driver located at /usr/standalone/i386/apfs.efi and load it to apfs volumes (I have no idea how GRUB will handle that)

> Put the MacOS bootloader in a place where GRUB can read it

There's a boot.efi in the EFI partition that you can try chainloading.

> Use GRUB to launch a 3rd-party EFI program that can load MacOS

Bootloaders that are used in hackintoshes such as Clover and OpenCore should work. Just disable or remove the kexts, drivers, and ssdt/dsdt patches.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get GRUB to utilize an EFI filesystem driver. I don't seem to have a macos-related boot.efi file in my ESP. I ended up going with option #3, but it seems like the worst possible solution.